# Mozilla Rhino Function inside function extraction

Tags: javascript, java, mozilla, rhino

I'm trying to figure out why Rhino is not able to get the function object inside a function.

According to the Rhino documentation, this is how you extract the function in the javascript from the java side.

```
Object fObj = scope.get("f", scope);
if (!(fObj instanceof Function)) {
    System.out.println("f is undefined or not a function.");
} else {
    Object functionArgs[] = { "my arg" };
    Function f = (Function)fObj;
    Object result = f.call(cx, scope, scope, functionArgs);
    String report = "f('my args') = " + Context.toString(result);
    System.out.println(report);
}
```

If I have this javascript, it will work just fine :

```
function f(){
    //some lines
}
```

However, the problem is this :

Assume I have a java function like this :

```
class RemoteJavaClass{
public void extractJavaScript(String targetFunctionName){
    Object fObj = scope.get(targetFunctionName, scope);
    if (!(fObj instanceof Function)) {
        System.out.println(targetFunctionName + " is undefined or not a function.");
    }
}
}
```

And a javascript like this in abc.js file :

```
function foo(){
    function inner(){
        //something
    }

    remrem.extractJavaScript("inner");
}
foo()
```

Before I execute the abc.js from java, I will have to "inject" the variable remrem as follows (in order for the javascript to be able to call the java function):

```
public void main (String args[]){
     scope = cx.initStandardObjects(new ImporterTopLevel(cx));
     RemoteJavaClass inst = new RemoteJavaClass();

     //inject the inst to javascript with variable "remrem"
     ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "remrem", Context.javaToJS(inst, scope));

    //finally we execute the script
    String scriptString = (read the javascript text from abc.js)
    Object result = cx.evaluateString(scope, scriptString, "Title", 1, null);
}
```

And the output would be :

```
 "inner is undefined or not a function."
```

However, if the script looks like this, then Rhino will be able to extract inner. If the whole thing is not inside a function, then Rhino won't have any problem extracting the inner function.

```
function inner(){
    //something
}
remrem.extractJavaScript("inner");
```

I've played around enough with the scope, and tried this but didn't work. The hypothesis is that Rhino was looking for inner in the global scope and so I went ahead and tried to look it up in the function scope but to no avail, it didn't work.

```
Object fObj = scope.get("f", scope);
if (!(fObj instanceof Function)) {
    System.out.println("f is undefined or not a function.");
} else {
    Object functionArgs[] = { "my arg" };
    Function f = (Function)fObj;
    Object result = f.call(cx, **fObj**, **fObj**, functionArgs);
    String report = "f('my args') = " + Context.toString(result);
    System.out.println(report);
}
```

And still I got the error :

```
org.mozilla.javascript.UniqueTag@11769f4c: NOT_FOUND
```

Does anyone have a good experience with Rhino and help me out?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is really old, but since I was struggling with a similar problem last week, I hope that my answer helps others with the same subject. You were right assuming that Rhino was looking in the global scope and therefore you need to access the scope of the foo function first. However, you cannot access inner functions in JavaScript like that. One way to do that is to follow the Revealing Module Pattern. You can check out more about this pattern with this link: [JavaScript Module Pattern Basics](https://coryrylan.com/blog/javascript-module-pattern-basics).

So, one way is to write the script like the following:

```
// Define the Foo module
var Foo = (function() {
    // Variables and other module functions
    // ...

    function inner() {
    }

    // Export public functions of the module
    return {
        inner: inner
    };
})();
```

Then, with Rhino you can access the inner function like the following:

```
Context context = Context.enter();

// Assume that the script is stored in a String variable called "s"

try {
    ScriptableObject globalScope = context.initStandardObjects();
    context.evaluateString(globalScope, s, "script", 1, null);

    // We now have access to the scope of the Foo module
    ScriptableObject fooScope = (ScriptableObject) globalScope.get("Foo", globalScope);
    final Function function = (Function) fooScope.get("inner", fooScope);
    final Object result = function.call(context, fooScope, fooScope, new Object[] {});

    // ...          
    } finally {
        Context.exit();
    }
}
```